# Word conjugation with Django i18n and gettext

Tags: django, internationalization, gettext

Currently, I have the following code in a template file in my Django project:

```
{% blocktrans with type=content.get_type %}Edit this {{ type }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

The `{{ type }}` is a string that can have values such as `"lecture"` and `"exercise"`. Here is the output in the `.po` file:

```
msgid "Edit this %(type)s"
msgstr ""
```

This works fine for languages such as English that don't conjugate objects. For languages that do, such as Finnish, this will cause problems.

In Finnish, the noun "lecture" translates to "luento", and the partitive form required in this specific case is conjugated "luento**a**". The noun "exercise" translates to "tehtävä" or "harjoitus", whose partitive forms are "tehtävä**ä**" and "harjoitus**ta**".

Is there a way to, for example, add specific translations for the words in cases such as this? Or maybe have some kind of condition based way to fill `msgstr`?

Obviously the following doesn't work, because the conjugated forms of the words end in different characters:

```
msgstr "Muokkaa tätä %(type)sa"
```

(Which would correctly result in "luentoa", but incorrectly result in "tehtäväa".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU's [gettext manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Preparing-Strings.html) advises that people translate whole sentences as much as possible:

> Entire sentences are also important because in many languages, the declination of some word in a sentence depends on the gender or the number (singular/plural) of another part of the sentence. There are usually more interdependencies between words than in English. The consequence is that asking a translator to translate two half-sentences and then combining these two half-sentences through dumb string concatenation will not work, for many languages, even though it would work for English. That’s why translators need to handle entire sentences.

Let's suppose you get the structure `"Edit this %(type)s"` to work for Finnish. As soon as you want to support French, for instance, it won't work. With the types you mentioned you'd have to have these sentences in French:

```
Éditer cette leçon
Éditer cet exercice
```

(The first sentence might have to be translated as `Éditer ce cours`. Which of "leçon" or "cours" is best depends on what "lecture" in English refers to precisely in the context in which you are using it.) You see the problem, depending on what word you use, you may need "cet", "cette", or "ce" in front of your `type`.

Comment: The example in French convinced me, that this is the correct principle for working with translations.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you do not have many different types maybe the simplest possibility so solve this issue could be to just make the phrase as a whole translatable:

```
{% if content.get_type == 'lecture' %}
  {% trans "Edit this lecture" %}
{% else if content.get_type == '.....'
  ...
{% endif %}
```

Otherwise you would have to prepare the `type` string before and set some [Contextual Markers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers) which is probably more work than necessary if there are only a few types.

Comment: I ended up using this method, with the if-elif-elif-...-elif-endif sequence wrapped within a `{% with type=content.get_type %}...{% endwith%}`. The answer by @Louis enlightened why this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to rely on `pgettext` to provide a context for your translation.

e.g.

```
from django.utils.translation import pgettext_lazy

type_translations = {
    'lecture': pgettext_lazy('partitive', 'lecture'),
    'exercise': pgettext_lazy('partitive', 'exercise'),
}
```

Comment: Interesting. This might indeed be one way to do it, and I might use it for something else, although generally – and in my specific problem – I think the solutions in answers by @Louis and Bernhard Vallant are better.

Comment: I agree above answers are better.